# Adding second inner loop though a map

Tags: java, loops, dictionary

I am trying to add two loops to loop though the same map. Once for the keys and once for the values. The key holds the currency's and the values holds the list. I want to loop though each list for each currency. Originally I was looping though the merged list as seen below, but noticed it was adding the two currency together not as intended so decided to keep separate them with a map and loop though each currency separately. How would I correct both loops to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have populated data structures you can use the `forEach()` methods on the `Collection` API, as follows:

```
Map<Currency, List<LiquidityFacility> map = ...

map.forEach((k, v) -> {  // iterate through all items in the map, k = key, v = value

    v.forEach(liquidityFacility -> {
        doSomething(k, liquidityFacility);  // k is currency, this will happen for every item in this currency's list
    });
});
```

EDIT (for those on Java version lower than 8)

The above code can also be written without lambdas and `forEach`:

```
for (Map.Entry<Currency, List<LiquidityFacility>> entry : map) {
    Currency currency = entry.getKey();
    List<LiquidityFacility> list = entry.getValue();

    for (LiquidityFacility lf : list) {
        doSomething(currency, lf);
    }
}
```

This is equivalent to the Java 8 version, and uses the for-each loop, made available with Iterators in Java 5.

Comment: forEach doesn't seem to be available on my version of Java

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating over the entries in the outer loop and interating over the values in the inner loop.

```
for (Entry<Currency, List<LiquidityFacility>> entries : ccyEntities.entrySet()) {

    Currency currency = entries.getKey();

    for (LiquidityFacility manualCorrectionLiquidityFacility : entries.getValue() ){
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks like it should work although its giving me cannot resolve symbol errors on entry and cannot resolve method on getKey and getValue

Comment: You have to import `java.util.Map.Entry` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) (should be available since Java 1.2)